# Некорректно работает метод push

Tags: javascript, массивы, push

не работает метод push в js.
Код следующий:

```
  let yDelta = []
  let yyy = []
  yDelta = [10]
  console.log(yDelta.slice())
  yyy.push(yDelta.slice())
  console.log('yyy', yyy)
```

Почему-то в переменную yyy записывается пустой массив
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А ты пробовал мышкой открыть этот самый массив `0: Array[]`. Может там что-то есть. Кроме того если ты это делаешь в дебагере VSCode, после выхода из него он уже может и не отображаться. Попробуй установи точку останова - он там 100% есть.

Comment: сделай `JSON.stringify(yyy)` при выводе

Comment: Да, действительно! Это просто моя невнимательность, данные в массив записываются. Спасибо